# converting string to reference points for canvas drawing

Tags: javascript, python, django, html, canvas

I'm toying with the idea of being able to change a simple text diagram into coordinates for drawing in a HTML5 canvas.

Saying that I have the following Text diagram, for hypothetical purposes lets imagine this is stored in a textfield in a django model.

```
     1
     2
  3  L  4
   5 6 7
     8
```

What I want, is to be able to draw this as onto a canvas, by figuring out at what point each number (or letter) is in the string. Spaces are also important.

I have no idea where to even start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a data model that can be used to build an image with CANVAS. One such model is a two dimensional array.

You can write a function that parses the text area and uses the index of each element to define a relative index with other elements. This can be done by calling split with an empty string and iterating through the returned array. You can keep track of the row number and the column number while iterating. After each newline character (`'\n'`) is found, you can reset the column count to 0.

Please note that if you'd like to have a relatively accurate text area image that contains different characters, you should use a monospace font such as Courier.

For example, given the following html page content:

```
<textarea id="area" cols="40" rows="10" style="font-family:Courier;">
            0
            0 
            0
       0    0    0
         0  0  0
           0 0
            0
</textarea>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

This example uses a plain html text area instead of django but it shows you the general approach.

We can compute the two dimensional array assuming that a new line in the text area will be a new row in our CANVAS image:

```
var area = document.getElementById("area");
var text = area.textContent;

var array = text.split('');

var row = 0;
var col = 0;
var colArray = [];
var rowArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++)
{
    var c = array[i];
    if(c === '\n')
    {
        rowArray[row] = colArray;
        colArray = [];

        row++;
        col = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        colArray[col] = c;

        col++;
    }
}
```

You can then build your CANVAS image by traversing through the two dimensional array, where `x` is the x-coordinate and `y` is the y-coordinate.

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var r = 20;
var xScale = 20;
var yScale = 40;
console.log(rowArray);
for(y=0; y<rowArray.length; y++)
{
    var row = rowArray[y];
    for(var x=0; x<row.length; x++)
    {
        var val = row[x];
        if(val != " ")
        {
            //Draw something at position [x,y] (or some transformation of it)
            var xCoord = x * xScale;
            var yCoord = y * yScale;

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(xCoord, yCoord, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'pink';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.fillText(val, xCoord, yCoord+5);
            ctx.stroke();  


        }
    }
}
```

You may need to use a different transformation for the x-coordinate than y-coordinate in CANVAS depending on how you'd like to display the image.

You can run this in JSFiddle to play with it.

**Edit:** added text fill as well. You can play around with the locations.

**Edit 2:** added center text positioning within the circle.

Comment: I've had a play around in JSFiddle with this, I'm no JS expert, I was looking to do it in python but this works much better.  However I have no idea what i'm doing with canvas, http://jsfiddle.net/2xxn782h/13/ how would I get the actual value to show in the middle of the arc? and I need the arc to be at least a radius of about 20px for some reason on JSFiddle, it's showing up as an oval not a complete circle.

Comment: edited to include text in your JSFiddle.  The oval issue is caused by setting the canvas width and height to 100%, which stretches the image.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following string:

```
raw_str = """\
     1
     2
  3  L  4
   5 6 7
     8"""
```

You can start by building a character to coordinate mapping:

```
rows = s.split('\n')
mapping = {}
for y, r in enumerate(rows):
    for x, c in enumerate(r):
        if c != ' ':
           mapping[c] = (x, y)
```

BTW, the mapping building part can also be written in one line using dict comprehension:

```
{c: (x, y) for y, r in enumerate(rows) for x, c in enumerate(r) if c != ' '}
```

Now you should get a mapping like this:

```
{'1': (5, 0),
 '2': (5, 1),
 '3': (2, 2),
 '4': (8, 2),
 '5': (3, 3),
 '6': (5, 3),
 '7': (7, 3),
 '8': (5, 4),
 'L': (5, 2)}
```

You can encode it in JSON and pass it to the front end as input for some Javascript canvas drawing function.